# code::blocks createprocess "No such file or directory" no idea how to fix

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw, codeblocks, mingw32

I am VERY new to using the code::blocks compiler and It doesn't seem to be working.

I downloaded the code::blocks and mingw package of of there website and I ran a very simple program that would say "hello world" and every way I try it I keep getting this error:

> mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g  -c C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\console_test\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o.

I have looked at all the other articles in stack overflow and I keep seeing people saying to set the enviroment variables or run mingw in a different directory but I have no idea how to do that.

The program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: my bad, i meant the code blocks IDE and mingw compiler

Comment: `mingw32-g++.exe ...etc` is not an error, it's just a compiler commandline. Show us the complete build log (from the **Build log** tab, not the **Build messages** tab), including the error. Post the information in the question.